# Extend the documentation that Eclipse shows on hover

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm working in a project where all comments are of this form:

```
/** Function definition
 *******************************************************************************
 * @param param1 description
 *
 * @return foo   description
 */
/*
 * REVISION HISTORY:
 *    John Doe, February 14, 2014
 *       created
 ******************************************************************************/
 int bar(int param1)
 {
     ....
 }
```

When I hover over the function name (`bar`) Eclipse only shows the part of the comment with the revision change along with the function body:

```
/*
 * REVISION HISTORY:
 *    John Doe, February 14, 2014
 *       created
 ******************************************************************************/
 int bar(int param1)
 {
     ....
 }
```

Is it possible to make Eclipse also shows the upper part of the comment (the actual documentation)?

Comment: My memory is pretty shaky (haven't worked in Eclipse in a long time) but I imagine you should combine the two multi-line comment blocks into one. (Don't `*/` and then `/*` a new block.) I don't think Eclipse can be changed to support this with existing code. I could easily be wrong though (hence commenting instead of posting an "answer') :)

Comment: I know it's because of the splitting blocks, but I'm not the one who wrote this project, I'm trying to read it